# DataTemplate bound items not changing with bound content

Tags: c#, mvvm, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a set of tabs I'm displaying in an Avalonia `TabControl`, each represented by a `TabModel` object.

`TabModel.cs`:

```
public class TabModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I want each tab to have a `TextBlock` as its title (similar to [the example from the docs](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/tabcontrol#binding-support)) and a custom control as the body. When loading the `TabControl`, the titles and body display properly. However, when I modify the `Name` or `Content` fields, the controls won't update. When `Content` is changed by the control (through the `TwoWay` binding), the change is reflected in the field and any changes made by the code are forgotten.

Xaml:

```
<TabControl Items="{Binding Tabs}">

    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeDataTemplate DataType="models:TabModel">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </TreeDataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <TreeDataTemplate DataType="models:TabModel">
            <controls:BoundEditor
                BoundText="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="BoundEditor" />
        </TreeDataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your model is a plain POCO. **P**lain **O**ld **C**LR **O**bject.

What you need is a ViewModel ...

```cs
public class TabModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now every time the `Name` setter is called, it will check to see if the value is new, update it if it is, and then will notify UI to update.